# search in big files performance difference

Tags: c#

I checked 2 ways to search in big files. 
I tested on 500mb size file. 
1st way took 9500ms and 2nd way took 11500ms.
How could it happen? 
Buffering is faster than accessing the resources on each iteration.
Linq is more powerfull than foreach search.
Is it trouble with memory allocation?

1:

```
  var __file = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
  var line = "";
  while ((line = __file.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
      var firstOccurrence = line.Contains(contains);
   }

  __file.Close();
```

2:

```
  var lines = File.ReadAllLines(_file);
  var firstOccurrence = lines.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Contains(contains));
```

Comment: I can't really say with any certainty, so others can chime in, but I think `ReadAllLines()` isn't exactly a super performant iirc.

Comment: Loading 500mb file is probably quite expensive and it's a lot of lanes. With lot of items in collection List won't be the most performant collection to perform search on.

Comment: _Linq is more powerfull than foreach search_ If you mean faster, no it isn't.

Comment: ~10 seconds sounds like a long time to search only a half gigabyte of text.  Is this 500 MB of 2-character lines or million-character lines or something in between?  How did you time the execution?  `DateTime.Now`, `Stopwatch`, a wall clock, something else?  How many runs did you perform?

Comment: yes stopwatch, runs change nothing, simple MPQ files from wow/data folder about 15k rows

Comment: For benchmark things in .net, you should probably use a benchmark tool, like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet). There are many things that can influence the results. Quote: _"Benchmarking is really hard (especially microbenchmarking), you can easily make a mistake during performance measurements."_

Answer (score 2):

In your first code snippet, you don't stop looping when you find a match. Try something like this:

```
while ((line = __file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var firstOccurrence = line.Contains(contains);
    if (firstOccurrence)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

In your second code snippet, you read the entire file into memory, and then start looking through it line-by-line. This is different to your first code snippet, where you read the file off disk one line at a time.

The equivalent method is [`File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_ReadLines_System_String_) -- this reads the file line-by-line:

```
var firstOccurrence = File.ReadLines(_file).FirstOrDefault(l => l.Contains(Contains));
```

Comment: was not actual needed in my case i found nothing